# Recorrer un array, si está la palabra 'lobo' devolver true, si no está; false

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, booleano

Este es mi codigo para solucionar el ejercicio pero no me funciona ¿Me podres decir que esta mal?

```
function loboEstaONoEsta(array) {
 for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if(array[i] === 'lobo'){
   return true;
  }else{
   return false;      
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Explicación del error:

El error está en que a cada evaluación que se haga en el **`for`**, la respuesta será el primer bucle que haga y se quedará pegado ahí, es decir, la primera evaluación en este caso será la primera posición de tu array, en donde estás verificando si la primera posición del array es **`lobo`** retornando **`true`**, de lo contrario retorna **`false`**:

```js
function loboEstaONoEsta(array) {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 'lobo') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(loboEstaONoEsta(["perro", "gato", "lobo"]))
console.log(loboEstaONoEsta(["gato", "lobo", "perro"]))
console.log(loboEstaONoEsta(["lobo", "perro", "gato"]))
```

---

###### Solución del problema:

La solución sería que cuando en cada evaluación no encuentre la palabra **`lobo`**, continúe evaluando hasta encontrarlo y entrar en el **`if`**. Si en todas las evaluaciones nunca encuentra la palabra **`lobo`**, se saldrá del bucle y retornará **`false`**, veamos:

```js
function loboEstaONoEsta(array) {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 'lobo') {
      return true; // si encuentra, retorna true.
    } else {
      continue; // si no encuentra, sigue evaluando.
    }
  }
  return false; // si nunca encontró, retorna false.
}

console.log(loboEstaONoEsta(['perro', 'gato', 'lobo'])); // hay lobo
console.log(loboEstaONoEsta(['lobo', 'perro', 'gato'])); // hay lobo
console.log(loboEstaONoEsta(['perro', 'gato', 'loro'])); // no hay lobo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya entendí.

Comment: Ya lo volví a poner, solo estaba probando las funciones de la plataforma, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tu explicación fue muy clara.

Comment: Me alegro que le haya servido mi ayuda, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Se utiliza el metodo some, validando startsWith

```js
  const array = ["gato", "lobo"];
  function loboEstaONoEsta(array) {
    return array.some((item) => item.startsWith("lobo"));
  }
  console.log(loboEstaONoEsta(array));
```

Comment: @masterguru   ya  modifique